# Trigger existing jquery with URL hash

Tags: jquery, url, hash

I have any existing jQuery on a page that changes the layout/masonry depending on the onclick selection. Content includes sections on advertising, music and photography. I would like to be to run the same functions when using a url hash.

Eg. foo.com/#advertising would run this specific function;

```
$('#show_advertising').click(function() {
    $('.advertisingon').slideDown('fast', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    });
    $('.advertisingoff').slideUp('fast', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    });
});
```

Here is the full query as it stands.

```
<script>
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
var $masonry = $('#masonry-content_fmzq1ep27, #masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy1, #masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy2, #masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy3, #masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy4, #masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy5,#masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy6, #masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy7, #masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy8, #masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy9, #masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy10');
$('#show_all').click(function() {  
    $('.allon').slideDown('fast', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    });
    });
$('#show_music').click(function() {
    $('.musicon').slideDown('fast', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    });
    $('.musicoff').slideUp('fast', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    }); 
});
$('#show_advertising').click(function() {
    $('.advertisingon').slideDown('fast', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    });
    $('.advertisingoff').slideUp('fast', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    });
});
$('#show_photographer').click(function() {
    $('.photographeron').slideDown('fast', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    });
    $('.photographeroff').slideUp('fast', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    });
});
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: `window.location.hash` contains the current hash

Comment: Thanks David. Although I'm not sure how to call upon that window.location.hash within this query?

Answer (score 1):

From page load:

```
<script>
$(function(){

    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash == "advertising")
    {
        //Do advertising code here
    }

});
</script>
```

On hash change:

```
window.onhashchange = function(){

    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash == "advertising")
    {
        //Do advertising code here
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks David. I told the following however this isn't working. Should I amend the original query or just duplicate the same again within the new window.location.has function.

Comment: I would make your code into a function and call the function in both places. That way you're not duplicating code.

Comment: Thanks David. Makes sense. It not quite at that level though I'm afraid. Not sure how to define this as a function inside or outside the larger query.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding this as per your suggestion, below the original full query...

$(function(){

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash == "advertising")
{
$('#show_advertising').click(function() {
    $('.advertisingon').slideDown('fast', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    });
    $('.advertisingoff').slideUp('fast', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    });
});
}
```

});

Comment: `.click(function(){` binds the interior function to the click event on the selected element. Just do the inside part. The .slidedown and .slideup part

Comment: Appreciate your help David! Much appreciated. I might be a little out of my depth here though today. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I now now... unfortunately still not triggering that #show_advertising function when going to foo.com/#advertising. The onclick version still functions correctly. I get the feeling that it not being part of the larger query above means it's missing out on some important elemets such as the "var" for the masonry.

```
<script>
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
var $masonry = $('#masonry-content_fmzq1ep27, #masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy1, #masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy2, #masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy3, #masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy4, #masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy5,#masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy6, #masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy7, #masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy8, #masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy9, #masonry-content_HomeHeadingTy10');
$('#show_all').click(function() {  
    $('.allon').slideDown('fast', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    });
    });
$('#show_music').click(function() {
    $('.musicon').slideDown('fast', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    });
    $('.musicoff').slideUp('fast', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    }); 
});
$('#show_advertising').click(function() {
    $('.advertisingon').slideDown('fast', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    });
    $('.advertisingoff').slideUp('fast', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    });
});
$('#show_photographer').click(function() {
    $('.photographeron').slideDown('fast', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    });
    $('.photographeroff').slideUp('fast', function() {
        $masonry.masonry();
    });
});
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

$(function(){

    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash == "advertising")
    {
    $('#show_advertising') {
        $('.advertisingon').slideDown('fast', function() {
            $masonry.masonry();
        });
        $('.advertisingoff').slideUp('fast', function() {
            $masonry.masonry();
        });
    });
    }

});